# Replaced selection with channel, can't edit selected area

Tags: gimp

I am familiarizing myself with GIMP using an online tutorial. The tutorial showed me how to use the selection editor to save my selection to a channel (using the button I circled in red). Then, after deselecting all, I was able to replace my current selection with the previously created channel (button circled in green).

Once I restore the selection in this way, I'm unable to do some of the same operations I could do when I made the selection initially. For instance, I'm unable to hit Ctrl+X to cut out the red portion of the image. Clicking back inside the image does not put things back to normal, and neither does hitting the escape key. Is there something I need to do so that I can edit my selection as usual?

[image]

Additional info:

If I deselect all and manually create a new selection after following the steps listed above, I still can't perform the usual edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the selected "drawable"(*) is the channel you just played with so this is where you editing happens. You have to go back to the Layers list and select a layer again.

(*) A "drawable" is something on which you can draw: layer, layer mask, or channel. There is only one active at a time in an image.

Comment: Thanks! FYI for others - the layers list is one of the tabs (along with Channels and Paths) that appears on the right side of my screenshot, about half way down. Just a small detail I needed to look up, so I thought I would mention it for anyone else with this question.